# Comparing 2 Linear/Contiguous 2D Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, contiguous

Hey i've been bothering with contiguous and linear allocated memory spaces out of good habit purposes.

I've been wondering if there is in somehow a capability to simply compare 2 Contiguously allocated 2D Array's.

Both are allocated like these, both the board and the game piece.

```
map->board = malloc(sizeof(char[map->x][map->y + 1]));
```

a board looks like this

```
000 ..............................
001 ..............................
002 ..X...........................
003 ..............................
004 ..............................
005 ..............................
006 ..............................
007 ..............................
008 ..............................
009 ..............................
010 ..............................
011 ...........................O..
012 ..............................
013 ..............................
```

The pieces look like these.

```
Piece 4 7 Piece 4 5: Piece 3 6:
...*... .**.. .****.
...*... .***. **....
...*... ..*.. *.....
..***.. .....
```

The purpose is for a piece to overlap '1' already placed token, and not exceed the dimensions.

However i'm unable to properly check if a piece exceeds the boards dimensions because it is a single dimensional array allocated with the size of a 2D Array, nor am i able to compare multiple rows.

Would i be better off just using Pointer-to-Pointer arrays?

Comment: You can compare arrays with `memcmp` but if you are comparing `struct`s (or arrays of) then unused space in the `struct` padding might cause an apparent difference which isn't effectively so. It's unclear what you are asking though: the question seems to go on to ask if you can compare the value of every element against a limit, with a single instruction.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your reply i've updated the post to be more informative.

Comment: You can do the 1D to 2D conversions explicitly, or you could use a pointer to a variably defined array, e.g. `char (*board)[map->y + 1] = (char (*)[map->y + 1])map->board;` and access the elements as `board[i][j]`.